# Unicode characters only partially supported in PHP / MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, unicode, iso-8859-1

I wrote a PHP script that creates 5 databases and inserts some data (using `$mysqli->multi_query`). When I tried it out, unicode (ä ö ü ß •) was broken, so I called `utf8_decode` on the whole sql query. However, this worked only for **ä ö ü**, not for **ß •** and not for uppercase **Ä Ö Ü**. This really confuses me.

Output of ß: �?Ÿ

I'm not a specialist in different character encodings, but until now, I always managed to get the proper output.

All my files are encoded in UTF-8 and the meta tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

is in every website.

Can someone help me on this?

Here are parts of the SQL query (it's really, really long)

```sql
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Erstellungszeit: 22. Mrz 2017 um 21:29
-- Server-Version: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- PHP-Version: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;


CREATE TABLE `forum` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `autor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `datum` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

**. . .**

```sql
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: If you're using UTF-8, then why `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`?

Comment: `latin1` is the *wrong* characterset (for storing UTF8 encoded unicode characters.  The latest versions of mysql support `utf8mb4` characterset.

Comment: Until now it worked, so I didn't dare to change it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through you'll need to go through at in its entirety, after seeing your comment below. There's probably a very simple answer for it. I have an idea.

Comment: Thanks. This helped!

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not **ever** use the PHP `utf8_decode()` function. The only thing it will do is irrecoverably mangle UTF-8 data, by (poorly) converting it to ISO8859-1. Remove it from anywhere it appears in your application.
2. Your table has `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`. Change that to `utf8mb4` to store Unicode text:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `forum` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
   ```

   If *and only if* your MySQL install is too old to support `utf8mb4`, use `utf8` instead. The `utf8` character set supports a limited subset of Unicode (in particular, it does not support emoji), but will at least support a wider selection of characters than `latin1`.

Comment: So, now it is displayed correctly in phpMyAdmin, but not on the website. Every non-ascii character is a �.

Comment: I figured it out. I have to call `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");` every time I create a connection. Finally it works :)

Comment: @Aloso which is exactly what i had in mind when I posted my comment up there ;-) was probably all you need to do also.

Comment: Do not blindly use `ALTER .. CONVERT TO` -- that applies in one scenario, but not all.  If you have utf8 bytes in a latin1 column, you need two `ALTERs`, neither of which uses `CONVERT TO`.

Comment: @RickJames Right. This advice was given under the assumption that there wasn't any meaningful Unicode data in the table yet.